# Multi-Threading or GPU calculations

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna, gpgpu, bitcoin

I'm currently attempting to create a Bitcoin Miner written in C# XNA.

https://github.com/Generalkidd/XNAMiner

Now the problem is, the actual number crunching of the Miner seems to be taking up too much CPU time and therefore, the UI of the program pretty much freezes at launch, although I do believe the calculations are still happening in the background despite the window being frozen and unresponsive. I tried implementing Aphid's ParallelTasks library and migrated some of the for-loops into a different thread. I didn't fully understand how these parallel for-loops worked and thus the version I created did not iterate correctly, however, the program did speed up a lot. There were still a couple for-loops left as well as a bunch of foreach loops.

What's the easiest and most efficient way to optimize my code? Should I try moving each loop into its own thread? Or try moving entire methods into their own threads? Or would it be possible to use the GPU for these calculations (it'd ultimately be better that way given the state of CPU mining).

Comment: Why XNA? Just so that you can use the gpu? And yes, you need to make your calculations on a different thread than the GUI. From there you can make more sub-threads for your sub-calculations.

Comment: I chose to write this in XNA because it expands the number of platforms people can use for bitcoin mining (eg. Xbox 360 & Windows Phone). However, I don't know how to properly move all the calculations to a different thread because it seems to be unable to return values to the main thread. I'm new to multi-threaded programming.

Comment: Take a look at [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). And you don't want to be running those types of calculations on an xbox or phone. They don't have the horsepower.

Comment: Reconsider the use of XNA if you intend to create a serious BitCoin miner. Phones and XBoxes are not appropriate hardware for this type of activity.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying out backgroundworker as we speak. I have to adjust the structure a bit in order to accommodate my code first. I know the Xbox 360 and Windows Phone aren't particularly powerful compared to PC's, however, it's still a good amount of computational power just lying around so I figured I'd take advantage of it. Every bit of computational power adds up.

Comment: If you really want to make your code more accessible for different platforms, take a look at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) which runs on linux, mac and windows. If you really want to stick to XNA for some reason, the mono version is called [Mono Game](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) which works on a huge amount of platforms.

Comment: if you can fit your code into the XBox's pixel-shader, it has a bit of power. but it depends on what functions you use... it's good with some things, not with other stuff... fillrate is one of the better features, I believe...

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are doing this as an educational effort, as CPU/GPU mining has become obsolete since 2011. You can barely make your hardware investment even with free electricity. ASICs are the new thing for mining now.

[Different GPU/CPU hash rates](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Non-specialized_hardware_comparison)

[Mining Calculator](https://alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator)